# C# - LINQ Statements with OR clauses

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use LINQ to return a list of tasks that are in one of three states. These states are:

10 - Completed
11 - Incomplete
12 - Skipped

The state is available through a property called "TaskStateID". I can do this in LINQ with just one state as shown here:

```
var filteredTasks = from task in tasks
                    select task;

// Do stuff with filtered tasks

string selectedComboBoxValue = GetFilterComboBoxValue();
if (selected ComboBoxValue == 3)
{
  filteredTasks = filteredTasks.Where(p => p.TaskStateID == 10); // How do I use an 'OR' here to say p.TaskStateID == 10 OR p.TaskStateID == 11 OR p.TaskStateID == 12
}
```

As shown in the comment above, how do I use an 'OR' in a LINQ statement to say p.TaskStateID == 10 OR p.TaskStateID == 11 OR p.TaskStateID == 12?

Thank you

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use the [`OR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28VS.80%29.aspx) (||) operator:

```
filteredTasks = filteredTasks.Where(p => p.TaskStateID == 10 || 
                                         p.TaskStateID == 11 || 
                                         p.TaskStateID == 12);
```

Answer (score 21):

```
var taskIds = new[]{10, 11, 12}

var selectedTasks = filteredTasks.Where(p => taskIds.Contains(p.TaskStateID))
```

Comment: As long as you put the lambda operator in the right place... oh, and remember that this will create a closure.

Comment: You can also only use Contains with strings.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [conditional OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346%28VS.80%29.aspx) operator:

```
filteredTasks = filteredTasks.Where(p => p.TaskStateID == 10 ||
                                         p.TaskStateID == 11 ||
                                         p.TaskStateID == 12);
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```
.Where(p => p.TaskStateID == 10 || p.TaskStateID == 11 || p.TaskStateID == 12)
```

Or you could also do something like this:

```
var states = new int[] {10,11,12};
filteredTasks = filteredTasks.Join(states, p => p.state, s => s, (p, s) => p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple: you use logical ORs.

```
filteredTasks.Where(p => p.TaskStateID == 10 || p.TaskStateID == 11 || p.TaskStateID == 12)
```

C# lambdas don't use a subset of the C# language: they use the whole language. Everything possible in C# is available to lambdas. The only requirement is that the expression must return the right type; and even then you can use curly braces to encompass more complex code:

```
p => { /* code block that has a return statement here */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
filteredTasks.Where(p => (p.TaskStateID == 10 || p.TaskStateID == 11 || p.TaskStateID == 12))
```