# Add LINQ Where Clause dynamically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code that gets files and folders from directory:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWith(".mp4") || s.EndsWith(".mov"));
```

However I have a comboBox with the file extensions I want to loop through, how can I add them dynamically to where clause?

Comment: Just to be sure; you want to extend the expression with `||` operators? If it's `&&` you can concatenate the `Where`'s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - LINQ Statements with OR clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439142/c-sharp-linq-statements-with-or-clauses)

Comment: You could also combine predicates as documented here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/meek/2008/05/02/linq-to-entities-combining-predicates/ but it's very cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of the extensions from the combo box, then you can use

```
.Where(s => ListOfExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s)));
```

Comment: Sorry I'm really new to C#, can you write the List bit?

Comment: @Chud37 Im not with VS to check but it seems odd you'd use a combobox as you cant multi select them, however you could try combobox1.items.contains.. maybe, but I havent tested it

Answer (score 0):

You could write String extension class

```
internal static class StringFileExtension
{
    public static bool EndsWithFromList(this string fileInfo, List<string> fileExtensions)
    {
        foreach (var extension in fileExtensions)
        {
            if (fileInfo.EndsWith(extension))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

and then just use it like this:

```
        List<string> fileExtensions = new List<string>
        {
            ".mp4",
            ".mov",
            "..."
        };

        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDIR.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(s => s.EndsWithFromList(fileExtensions));
```

don't forget include extensions namespace in usage place