# Filter list using linq with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to filter a list with two conditions. I need to first check whether the items are null or empty and then use them to filter the list.

```
filterPdfForms = pdfForms
                          .Where(n => n.lang == data.Lang)
                          .Where(n => data.FormKeys.Contains(n.key));
```

if `data.lang` is null or empty, I wouldn't use the filter
`data.FormKeys` is a comma separated string and again should be checked for being null or empty, if no, then use it to filter further

Comment: `Where(n => data.Lang == null || n.lang == data.Lang)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - LINQ Statements with OR clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439142/c-sharp-linq-statements-with-or-clauses)

Comment: data.FormKeys.Split(new char[] {','}).Contains(n.key)

Comment: Can you please provide some input data and your expected output for it?

Comment: `data` is not the variable of your `where`, right? so you could put the whole query in a `if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.lang)){}`, don't you? Or do completely misunderstand your issue...?